# How to add Mysql as a db in hyperledger fabric-ca?

Tags: mysql, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

I want to put my application on production and hence i want to add mysql as a db in fabric-ca. Has anyone tried it ? I'm stuck on it for a week now and can't find anything on the internet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why mysql and not PostgreSQL as it is designed to?

Something like...

```
# docker-compose.yaml

version: '2.4'

services:

  postgres:
    image: postgres:10.3-alpine
    restart: unless-stopped
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_DB=ca
      - POSTGRES_USER=admin_postgres
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=admin_postgres_password
    volumes:
      - /volumes/ca_postgres:/var/lib/postgresql/data

  fabric-ca:
    image: hyperledger/fabric-ca:1.4
    restart: unless-stopped
    environment:
      - FABRIC_CA_SERVER_PORT=7054
      - FABRIC_CA_HOME=/root/home
    volumes:
      - /volumes/ca_home:/root/home
    ports:
      - 7054:7054
```

You must previously prepare your fabric-ca-server-config.yaml into your FABRIC_CA_HOME:

```
# fabric-ca-server-config.yaml

# ...

db:
  type: postgres
  datasource: host=postgres port=5432 user=admin_postgres password=admin_postgres_password dbname=ca sslmode=disable

# ...
```

Comment: hi @kekomal, thank you for your reply. Can you tell how to check if my postgres is actually saving the files.

Comment: A dirty way to check it is by digging into /volumes/ca_postgres folder in the host or /var/lib/postgresql/data inside the container. You can also query the postgres "ca" database (maybe you want to expose 5432 port to do this). Or simply register an identity, restart your docker services and enroll it. As the identity still exists and nothing related has been saved inside your FABRIC_CA_HOME, it has been persisted in PostgreSQL.

Comment: bro can you tell how to add postgres using sslmode=verify-ca or verify-full. Thanks to you i am able to connect postgres with fabric-ca but with sslmode = require only but not using verify-ca or verify-full.